# how to retrieve value from two table in mysql using foreign Key is null?

Tags: mysql, database

i have two tables Test1 and Test2

### Test1 have id and Name

```
Id Name
1 rizwan
2 nadeem
3 ramiz
```

and second Table Test2 have middle name and foreign key

```
id MiddleName id_fk
1 Hashmi       1
2 Khan         3
```

now i want to select value from both table if value middle name is not present in second table then **Display only name from first name**

i have write a query for this

```
SELECT Test1.tName,Test2.tMidleName 
from Test1,Test2 
where Test1.idTest1=Test2.idTest1 
  AND  Test1.tName='nadeem';
```

---

**Above is query but if foreign key is null it will not show values**

what should i change in the query if foreign key is null? if it's null i want to show only name from first Table

Comment: Promote the use of  explict `JOIN` sintaxis, Aaron Bertrand wrote a nice article [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `LEFT JOIN`

```
SELECT Test1.tName, COALESCE(Test2.tMidleName , '') as tMidleName 
from Test1
LEFT JOIN Test2 
  ON Test1.idTest1=Test2.idTest1 
WHERE  Test1.tName='nadeem';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Test1.tName,Test2.tMidleName 
from Test1
LEFT JOIN Test2 
  ON Test1.idTest1 != Test2.idTest1 
  WHERE Test1.tName='nadeem';
```